# What is the religious significance of Christmas lights?

Tags: christmas, religious-practice

What is the religious significance of the modern practice to decorate the outside of the house and front yard with strings of light?  Is it entirely secular?

Comment: -1 for lack of research effort. You can read about the history of Christmas lights [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas_lights). There doesn't appear to be any specific religious meaning to it--it was a way to show off originally. And I guess it still is.

Comment: I have flagged this off topic as the OP has not demonstrated that Christmas lights are associated with Christianity (the religion) or even, "[is Christmas a Christian holiday?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/5144/why-is-christmas-on-december-25th)".  Secular questions are off topic.  Similarly, I could write a question, "What is the religious significance of participating in Christianity.SE?" - I do not think we want to go down this road.

Comment: @TheFreemason I would like to show that "the religious significance" of anything is a matter of personal opinion. That makes this primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 9):

Well, there certainly isn't anything in the Bible about it, for the simple reason that there isn't anything in the Bible about celebrating Christmas in the first place.  (Not to mention electricity!)  However, hanging or holding up lanterns to provide festive illumination after dark for festivals or celebrations is an ancient custom in many cultures, dating back to Old Testament days.  See the the [Parable of the Ten Virgins](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2025:1-13) for just one example.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything in the bible on Christmas lights, but in the Middle Ages, they used a candle as a sign of the star of Bethlehem. Originally candles were used, but in 1882 Edward Johnson invented the first string of electric Christmas lights. On a Christmas tree, the traditional topper is a star or a candle, then the lights around the tree symbolize a pathway to the star of Bethlehem where Jesus Christ was born.